# How to get registry Key name from an open Key Handle in Perl?

Tags: perl, registry

I have a perl function that takes an open registry key object. Now, I want to get the name of the key this object represents. How do I get the key Name?

I am using Win32::Registry module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing through the source, it doesn't look like Win32::Registry will let you take the handle and get back to the Key.  I see three ways around this:

1. Maintain a list of returned objects from `Open` and the path to them yourself.
2. Hack the module (subclass it, change the source) to do #1 for you.
3. Or extend the Win32::Registry API to do what's shown in this stackoverflow answer: [Determine path to registry key from HKEY handle in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937044/determine-path-to-registry-key-from-hkey-handle-in-c)