# How to print HKEY or convert it to string?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get the value of registry key and then to see it

following extract of code

```
HKEY hkey;

RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\SomeSoft\\Settings", 0, 0x20019u, &hKey);

printf("121 hkey= %s \n", hKey);
```

is compiling, but stopped at runtime.

Question: how do I convert hkey in something visible, like string 
in order to see it?

Comment: "casting" is not really a good tag for this question.  I am going to also assume C++ as you did not specify a language.

Comment: If you want to get the string representation for a given `HKEY` value (i.e. you want your program to print something like `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SomeSoft\Settings`) see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937044/determine-path-to-registry-key-from-hkey-handle-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

An `HKEY` is not a string, rather it is an integer value. So, what happens is that your program treats `hKey` as if it were a null-terminated array of `char` and presumably that's what leads to the runtime failure.

You must use an appropriate format string for the type of data that you have. This is one of the pitfalls of `printf` and is one of the reasons why, if you can, you should prefer the C++ stream output mechanism.

Note that `HKEY` is pointer sized. So if you want your code to work for both 32 and 64 bit processes then you will need to allow for that in your format string. The easiest thing is to treat it as a pointer and use `%p`.

You should also make sure that you perform error checking. You are ignoring the return value of `RegOpenKeyEx`, and you must not do that. I would not be at all surprised if the real problem with your code was revealed simply by paying heed to the value returned by the function.

And don't use magic constants for the `samDesired` parameter. Specify it by combining flags using the bitwise or operator. Or in your case, pass `KEY_READ`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "converting a `HKEY` to a string":

1. If you want to get the numeric value of the HKEY, print it like you would print a pointer, e.g.

   ```
   printf( "hkey = %p\n", hkey );
   ```
2. If you want to print the path represented by the `HKEY` handle, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937044/determine-path-to-registry-key-from-hkey-handle-in-c).
3. If you want to print the string value of the registry entry referenced by a `HKEY`, use the [`RegQueryValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

The returned HKEY is a handle.  Use `RegQueryValueEx` to get the actual registry value.