# Getting reg key path from Registry_TypeGroup1 class (Windows Event Tracing)

Tags: c++, winapi, etw

I need to track registry changes. I need  detailed information, so [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx) is not enough. So, the only way I found in Google is to use this horrible [Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

After configuring all stuff and actual getting the data, I have [`Registry_TypeGroup1 class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364108(v=vs.85).aspx) from [`EVENT_TRACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
[EventType{...}]class Registry_TypeGroup1 : Registry
{
  sint64 InitialTime;
  uint32 Status;
  uint32 Index;
  uint32 KeyHandle;
  string KeyName;
};
```

According to the documentation, `KeyName` is just the *Name of the registry key* and not the full key path for the given event. But the problem is that **I need the full path** for the key!

If I convert `KeyHandle` from `uint32` to `HKEY` and use [`NtQueryKey`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/nt%20objects/key/ntquerykey.html) ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937044/determine-path-to-registry-key-from-hkey-handle-in-c)) - the function will fail with an unknown status.

So, is there a way to retrieve the full Registry key path from the `EVENT_TRACE` instance of `EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_REGISTRY`?

(I am asking because I read somewhere that ProcMon uses Event Tracing and it shows the full Registry path for events... Or does it hook system calls to `Reg*` functions?)

Comment: [Filtering Registry Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545879.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I refused it, first time I found, because it requires kernel-mode driver and i have no idea how to write driver. I thought it would be easier to understand Event Tracing rather then how to write simple driver...

Comment: That's what ProcMon uses, starting with Windows Vista (source: [Sysinternals forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/monitor-registry-activities-in-detail_topic27467.html)). Versions targeting previous OS releases use system call hooking.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Thanks for the correction orthography

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3365ae1-b152-4e0c-9237-388770b6b638/obatin-the-full-key-path-of-the-registry-event?forum=etw), you can use KCBRundownEnd which can be seen in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/registry-typegroup1) to collect all the registries.
There are whole basename and KeyHandle in the log of KCBRundownEnd event, and you can match the KeyHandle to get the corresponding basenames.